# Select element grows differently than input in display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm getting an unexpected behavior [in my setup](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/qLgbc8se/). The inputs grow horizontally as expected but on the row with a select control, the growth seems to be distorted.

I suspected some style to be different but a close inspection led me nowhere. Googling gave nothing and I can't find anything about implicit margin nor padding for selects.

What is this about and how do I kill it?

```css
div.full-page {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: ghostwhite;
}

div.input-section {
  border: 3px none darkorchid;
  width: 600px;
}

div.input-title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid darkorange;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

div.input-row {
  border: 3px none darkolivegreen;
  display: flex;
}

div.input-element {
  border: 3px none darkcyan;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  // display:flex;
}

div.input-element input,
div.input-element select {
  width: 100%;
  // border: solid 1px mediumvioletred;
  // padding: 0;
  // margin: 0;
}

div.input-caption {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-page">

  <div>

    <div class="input-section">
      <div class="input-title">Title 1</div>

      <div class="input-row">
        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Uno</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Konrad">
        </div>
        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Duo</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Viltersten">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div #privs class="input-section">
      <div class="input-title">Title 2</div>

      <div class="input-row">
        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Tress</div>
          <input placeholder="Is really">
        </div>

        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Quatro</div>
          <select>
            <option>The one and only</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Using single line commenting `//` is invalid in CSS and could break your CSS and give very unpredictable result, where rules might not be applied properly, so use `/**/`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're using `flex-grow: 1` to size your flex items. That's fine when all items are identical or contain identical content.

Except one of your flex items is different. It has the `select` element. That will affect the sizing of the item because an initial value of a flex item is `flex-basis: auto`.

With `flex-basis: auto` the `flex-grow` property goes into effect *after* the width of the item is factored in. Because the width of your items are different, their size after `flex-grow` is applied will be different.

You need to use `flex-basis: 0`, which allows `flex-grow` to ignore the width of the item and focus only on the available space in the container.

Instead of `flex-grow: 1` use this:

- `flex: 1`

Which is shorthand for:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

See the spec for more details: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common

Also, to counter problems such as these, the spec recommends always using the `flex` shorthand as opposed to longhand properties:

> [**7.2. Components of
>   Flexibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)
>
> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex`
>   shorthand rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the
>   shorthand correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate
>   common uses.

Comment: tried to debug the same problem in my code for an hour and you saved me another 1-2 hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The parent of the select needs to be set at 100% for it to stretch since now it's constrained.

```
.input-element {width:100%;}
```

By the way, it has nothing to do with the flex-grow because the issue of width still existed when I removed that style, which led me to see it was the containing element's problem :)

https://jsfiddle.net/hhft4ke6/

```css
div.full-page {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: ghostwhite;
}

div.input-section {
  border: 3px none darkorchid;
  width: 600px;
}

div.input-title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid darkorange;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

div.input-row {
  border: 3px none darkolivegreen;
  display: flex;
}

div.input-element {
  border: 3px none darkcyan;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width:100%;
  // display:flex;
}

div.input-element input,
div.input-element select {
  width: 100%;
  // border: solid 1px mediumvioletred;
  // padding: 0;
  // margin: 0;
}

div.input-caption {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-page">

  <div>

    <div class="input-section">
      <div class="input-title">Title 1</div>

      <div class="input-row">
        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Uno</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Konrad">
        </div>
        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Duo</div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Viltersten">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div #privs class="input-section">
      <div class="input-title">Title 2</div>

      <div class="input-row">
        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Tress</div>
          <input placeholder="Is really">
        </div>

        <div class="input-element">
          <div class="input-caption">Quatro</div>
          <select>
            <option>The one and only</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure *"it has nothing to do with `flex-grow`"*, but your answer definitely works.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote. In fact I did the opposite and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the flex-items to be the same length, you should use the css 'flex' property, so just set div.input-element to flex:1.

Comment: I'm doing that. Your suggestion is simply a shortcut for it, isn't it?